# How to recover kali linux after removing windows 7 from dual boot

Tags: kali-linux

My system was like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuubO.png)

I was using Windows 7 and kali linux on dual boot most of the time I work with linux then I thought I should remove the window 7 and other local disk to merge the partition with the linux partition which was 40gb. I did remove windows with the help of GPARTED starting it on a usb bootable, after removing windows ntfs, which changed into unallocated and I merged it with ext4 linux partition to increase the space, after this process, restarting the Laptop screen displaying BootDevice not Found , Please install an operating system on your hardisk.
Hard Disk - (3F0)

Comment: Your windows was on the first partition, so I guess you extended from sda2 to sda1, right to left. This really messes up the boot process, the MBR can't find the boot disk anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a LiveUSB, back up everything in and under /home, reinstall Kali from scratch, restore files from backup.